# Javascript in Google App Scripts - Call Class Method inside OnClick

Tags: javascript, class, google-apps-script, onclick

I am building a simple Employee time off request form on a Google App Script website.  I have a button to add additional rows to the form (as well as other buttons, but lets just focus on one).  I also have reasons why I sometimes want these buttons disabled and enabled, so I have a function that performs this disabling/enabling. I store the name of the onclick function in a child  element of the button, so that I can remove it and reapply it abstractly (I want a single abstracted function that handles all three buttons without actually needing to know the relationships of the buttons to functions).

**What I am trying to do**
In button_EnableDisable(), when trying to enable the Button_PTO_AddInputRow button I grab the innerHTML contents of the child span (this is working as demonstrated with console.log), I then set the onclick attribute to the value of retrieved value (this is working as demonstrated with console.log). I then load the website (appears to load the form correctly), and I press the Button_PTO_AddInputRow to add a new input row to the table.

**What is not working**
When pressing Button_PTO_AddInputRow, I get the following console error: "Uncaught TypeError: this.addRowInputTable is not a function"

**CODE**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var nPTO = new PTO('TableContainer', 5);

});


class PTO {
  //self = this;

  constructor(container, nRows) {
    this.initialInputRows = nRows;

    this.formContainer = document.getElementById(container);
    this.table = document.createElement('table');
    this.generateFormButons();
    this.button_EnableDisable('Button_PTO_AddInputRow', 'enable');
    //this.button_EnableDisable('Button_PTO_SendRequest', 'enable');
    //this.button_EnableDisable('Button_PTO_ClearForm', 'enable');

    this.generateInputTable();
  }



  generateFormButons() {
    var child;
    var tt;
    var onclickHolder;

    this.btn_AddInputRow = document.createElement('a');
    this.btn_AddInputRow.setAttribute('id', 'x');
    this.btn_AddInputRow.setAttribute('style', 'margin: 5px 10px;');
    this.btn_AddInputRow.classList.add('tooltip');
    child = document.createElement('i');
    child.setAttribute('id', 'Button_PTO_AddInputRow');
    child.setAttribute('style', 'opacity:0.5;');
    child.classList.add('fas', 'fa-plus', 'fa-lg');
    this.btn_AddInputRow.appendChild(child);

    tt = document.createElement('span');
    tt.classList.add('tooltiptext');
    tt.innerHTML = 'Add a new entry row';
    this.btn_AddInputRow.appendChild(tt);

    onclickHolder = document.createElement('span');
    onclickHolder.setAttribute('id', 'x');
    onclickHolder.classList.add('Container_OnClickFunction');
    onclickHolder.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    onclickHolder.innerHTML = 'this.addRowInputTable()';
    child.appendChild(onclickHolder);

    this.formContainer.appendChild(this.btn_AddInputRow);

    /*
        this.btn_SendRequest = document.createElement('a');
        this.btn_SendRequest.setAttribute('id', 'x');
        this.btn_SendRequest.setAttribute('style', 'margin: 5px 10px;');
        this.btn_SendRequest.classList.add('tooltip');
          child = document.createElement('i');
          child.setAttribute('id', 'Button_PTO_SendRequest');
          child.setAttribute('style', 'opacity:0.5;');
          child.classList.add('far', 'fa-paper-plane', 'fa-lg');
          this.btn_SendRequest.appendChild(child);
          
          tt = document.createElement('span');
          tt.classList.add('tooltiptext');
          tt.innerHTML = 'Send Request for review';
          this.btn_SendRequest.appendChild(tt);
        this.formContainer.appendChild(this.btn_SendRequest);

        this.btn_ClearForm = document.createElement('a');
        this.btn_ClearForm.setAttribute('id', 'x');
        this.btn_ClearForm.setAttribute('style', 'margin: 5px 10px;');
        this.btn_ClearForm.classList.add('tooltip');
          child = document.createElement('i');
          child.setAttribute('id', 'Button_PTO_ClearForm');
          child.setAttribute('style', 'opacity:0.5;');
          child.classList.add('fas', 'fa-rotate', 'fa-lg');
          this.btn_ClearForm.appendChild(child);
          
          tt = document.createElement('span');
          tt.classList.add('tooltiptext');
          tt.innerHTML = 'Clear the form';
          this.btn_ClearForm.appendChild(tt);
        this.formContainer.appendChild(this.btn_ClearForm);

      */
  }

  generateInputTable() {
    var newRow;
    var newHeader;

    this.table.classList.add('Table');


    newRow = this.table.insertRow(-1);
    newRow.classList.add('Table_Row');
    newRow.classList.add('Table_Row_Headers');

    // Add Header Row

    newHeader = document.createElement('th');
    newRow.appendChild(newHeader);
    newHeader.setAttribute('id', 'x');
    newHeader.classList.add('Table_Header');
    newHeader.innerHTML = 'Delete';
    newHeader.value = 'Delete';

    newHeader = document.createElement('th');
    newRow.appendChild(newHeader);
    newHeader.setAttribute('id', 'x');
    newHeader.classList.add('Table_Header');
    newHeader.innerHTML = 'Staff';
    newHeader.value = 'Staff';

    newHeader = document.createElement('th');
    newRow.appendChild(newHeader);
    newHeader.setAttribute('id', 'x');
    newHeader.classList.add('Table_Header');
    newHeader.innerHTML = 'Time Off Type';
    newHeader.value = 'Time Off Type';

    newHeader = document.createElement('th');
    newRow.appendChild(newHeader);
    newHeader.setAttribute('id', 'x');
    newHeader.classList.add('Table_Header');
    newHeader.innerHTML = 'Date';
    newHeader.value = 'Date';

    newHeader = document.createElement('th');
    newRow.appendChild(newHeader);
    newHeader.setAttribute('id', 'x');
    newHeader.classList.add('Table_Header');
    newHeader.innerHTML = 'Duration Type';
    newHeader.value = 'Duration Type';

    newHeader = document.createElement('th');
    newRow.appendChild(newHeader);
    newHeader.setAttribute('id', 'x');
    newHeader.classList.add('Table_Header');
    newHeader.innerHTML = 'Half Day Period';
    newHeader.value = 'Half Day Period';

    newHeader = document.createElement('th');
    newRow.appendChild(newHeader);
    newHeader.setAttribute('id', 'x');
    newHeader.classList.add('Table_Header');
    newHeader.innerHTML = 'Start Time';
    newHeader.value = 'Start Time';

    newHeader = document.createElement('th');
    newRow.appendChild(newHeader);
    newHeader.setAttribute('id', 'x');
    newHeader.classList.add('Table_Header');
    newHeader.innerHTML = 'End Time';
    newHeader.value = 'End Time';

    newHeader = document.createElement('th');
    newRow.appendChild(newHeader);
    newHeader.setAttribute('id', 'x');
    newHeader.classList.add('Table_Header');
    newHeader.innerHTML = 'Request Status';
    newHeader.value = 'Request Status';

    newHeader = document.createElement('th');
    newRow.appendChild(newHeader);
    newHeader.setAttribute('id', 'x');
    newHeader.classList.add('Table_Header');
    newHeader.innerHTML = 'Request Date Time';
    newHeader.value = 'Request Date Time';

    newHeader = document.createElement('th');
    newRow.appendChild(newHeader);
    newHeader.setAttribute('id', 'x');
    newHeader.classList.add('Table_Header');
    newHeader.innerHTML = 'Request Note';
    newHeader.value = 'Request Note';

    newHeader = document.createElement('th');
    newRow.appendChild(newHeader);
    newHeader.setAttribute('id', 'x');
    newHeader.classList.add('Table_Header');
    newHeader.innerHTML = 'Response Date Time';
    newHeader.value = 'Response Date Time';

    newHeader = document.createElement('th');
    newRow.appendChild(newHeader);
    newHeader.setAttribute('id', 'x');
    newHeader.classList.add('Table_Header');
    newHeader.innerHTML = 'Response Note';
    newHeader.value = 'Response Note';


    var c = 0;
    for (c = 0; c < this.initialInputRows; c++) {
      this.addRowInputTable();
    }

    this.formContainer.appendChild(this.table);

  }

  addRowInputTable() {

    var newRow;
    var newCell;
    var nRows;
    var lastRow;
    var rowID;
    var rCount;

    nRows = this.table.rows.length;


    if (nRows == 1) {
      rowID = "Table_Row_1";
      rCount = 1;
    } else {
      lastRow = this.table.rows[nRows - 1];
      rowID = lastRow.id;
      rCount = Number(rowID.replace("Table_Row_", ""));
      rCount = ((rCount * 1) + 1);
      rowID = "Table_Row_" + rCount;
    }

    newRow = this.table.insertRow(-1);
    newRow.setAttribute('id', rowID);
    newRow.classList.add(rowID);
    newRow.classList.add('Table_Row_Input');


    var btn = document.createElement('i');
    btn.setAttribute('id', 'Table_Row_Trash');
    btn.setAttribute('style', '');
    btn.classList.add('Icon_Button', 'fa-regular', 'fa-trash-can');
    newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    newCell.classList.add('Table_Cell');
    newCell.appendChild(btn);

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    newCell.setAttribute('id', 'TimeOff_StaffName');
    newCell.classList.add('Table_Cell');
    newCell.classList.add('UserInput_Request');
    //newCell.innerHTML = 'Chris';
    //newCell.value = 'Chris';
    newCell.innerHTML = newRow.classList.value

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    newCell.setAttribute('id', 'TimeOff_RequestType');
    newCell.classList.add('Table_Cell');
    newCell.classList.add('UserInput_Request');
    newCell.innerHTML = 'PTO';
    newCell.value = 'PTO';

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    newCell.setAttribute('id', 'TimeOff_RequestDate');
    newCell.classList.add('Table_Cell');
    newCell.classList.add('UserInput_Request');
    newCell.innerHTML = 'Tomorrow';
    newCell.value = 'Tomorrow';

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    newCell.setAttribute('id', 'TimeOff_DurationType');
    newCell.classList.add('Table_Cell');
    newCell.classList.add('UserInput_Request');
    newCell.innerHTML = 'Full Day';
    newCell.value = 'Full Day';

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    newCell.setAttribute('id', 'TimeOff_HalfDayPeriod');
    newCell.classList.add('Table_Cell');
    newCell.classList.add('UserInput_Request');
    newCell.innerHTML = 'Morning';
    newCell.value = 'Morning';

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    newCell.setAttribute('id', 'TimeOff_StartTime');
    newCell.classList.add('Table_Cell');
    newCell.classList.add('UserInput_Request');
    newCell.innerHTML = '10:00';
    newCell.value = '10:00';

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    newCell.setAttribute('id', 'TimeOff_EndTime');
    newCell.classList.add('Table_Cell');
    newCell.classList.add('UserInput_Request');
    newCell.innerHTML = '14:00';
    newCell.value = '14:00';

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    newCell.setAttribute('id', 'TimeOff_RequestStatus');
    newCell.classList.add('Table_Cell');
    newCell.classList.add('UserInput_Response');
    newCell.innerHTML = 'Approved';
    newCell.value = 'Approved';

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    newCell.setAttribute('id', 'TimeOff_RequestDateTime');
    newCell.classList.add('Table_Cell');
    newCell.classList.add('xxxxx');
    newCell.innerHTML = 'Yesterday';
    newCell.value = 'Yesterday';

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    newCell.setAttribute('id', 'TimeOff_RequestNote');
    newCell.classList.add('Table_Cell');
    newCell.classList.add('UserInput_Request');
    newCell.innerHTML = 'Please';
    newCell.value = 'Please';

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    newCell.setAttribute('id', 'TimeOff_ResponseDateTime');
    newCell.classList.add('Table_Cell');
    newCell.classList.add('xxxxx');
    newCell.innerHTML = 'Tomorrow';
    newCell.value = 'Tomorrow';

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    newCell.setAttribute('id', 'TimeOff_ResponseNote');
    newCell.classList.add('Table_Cell');
    newCell.classList.add('UserInput_Response');
    newCell.innerHTML = 'I will allow it';
    newCell.value = 'I will allow it';

  }

  deleteRowInputTable() {

  }

  clearInputTable() {

  }

  button_EnableDisable(btn, status) {


    var btn = document.getElementById(btn);
    var onclickHolder = btn.querySelector(".Container_OnClickFunction");
    console.log("onclickHolder.innerHTML: " + onclickHolder.innerHTML);


    if (status.toUpperCase() == 'ENABLE') {
      btn.style.opacity = 1;
      btn.classList.add("Icon_Button");
      btn.setAttribute("onclick", onclickHolder.innerHTML);
      btn.disabled = false;
    } else if (status.toUpperCase() == 'DISABLE') {
      btn.style.opacity = 0.5;
      btn.classList.remove("Icon_Button");
      btn.removeAttribute("onclick", '');
      btn.disabled = true;
    }
  }

  button_HideUnhide(btn, status) {
    var btn = document.getElementById(btn);
    if (status.toUpperCase() == 'HIDE') {
      btn.style.display = "none";
    } else if (status.toUpperCase() == 'UNHIDE') {
      btn.style.display = "block";
    }
  }

}
```

```css
.Table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #EDF4EE; //#C5DBAD;   
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.Table_Header {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.Table_Cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.Icon_Button {
  //box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px ;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Icon_Button:hover {
  //box-shadow: 0px 15px 25px -5px ;
  transform: scale(1.20);
}

.Icon_Button:active {
  //box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px ;
  transform: scale(0.80);
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  //display: inline-block;
  //border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css'>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>TESTING - HR PTO</h1>

  <div id="TableContainer"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

I have tried all kinds of permutations, but I just can't seem to get the class method to be recognized and called.

I saw a very old post suggesting there was a bug with setting this, and they used a self = this class variable, but that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: When the `onclick` attribute is a string, it's executed in the global scope. In the global scope, `this` is `window`, not the class instance.

Comment: In general, avoid using `onclick` attributes. Use `addEventListener()` with a proper closure as the argument. Why are you doing this by copying the onclick from `innerHTML` to an attribute?

Comment: Ahh that makes sense.  I will give addEventListener a try.  I am just putting the string name in the innerHTML of a hidden span to use it as a container to hold the relationship.  I am open to using other methods if you have recommendatrions.

Comment: If you use strings as code, they have to be in the global scope. You could define a global variable holding the `PTO` instance, and use `thatVariable.addRowInputTable()`.

Comment: Changing over to addEventListener() seems to get me closer, but I still can't seem to resolve the issue of converting the string to a function to include as a parameter to addEventListener().  I've tried both eval() and new Function(), and neither gets me closer to calling the desired function.

Comment: See my last comment. You can't use `this` when you're executing the code in the global scope.

Comment: The issue isn't with "this" it's that I am clearly not converting the string to an acceptable form for inclusion in addEventListener.  The last thing I tried was eval("var func = function(){ return '" +  onclickHolder.innerHTML + "' }") but func is not recognized with or without this (or nPTO in the global scope)

Comment: All you need is `addEventListener("click", function() {eval(onclickHolder.innerHTML);})`

Comment: Ah yes, that's a lot cleaner, and it works.  I also got the scope issue resolved.  Thanks for your help in pointing me in the right direction.  Ultimately, I moved the nPTO declaration to a global scope, then created a global pass-through function that uses nPTO to call class-based version of the AddRow function.  Ex: 

var nPTO;
function addRowInputTable()
{
  nPTO.addRowInputTable()
}  

I'll give it a unique function name, and probably move the entire abstraction to this function instead of the class function, but it's working.  Thanks!